# php inverted comma in a variable

Tags: php

I am trying to assign a string to a variable like that

`$start "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>"`

Its giving me error
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER

I think its because I am inserting " between and also ? 
How to solve this ?

Comment: Whenever you use something new and it does not work, first of all read the manual. A programming language is no different than for example like a machine for your kitchen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape it with a backslash:

```
$start="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
```

Or use a different quote:

```
$start='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
```

See the [*PHP manual page about strings*](http://php.net/string) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
$start='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
```

put single quotes

Answer (score 1):

**backslashes:**

```
$start = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" ;
```

or

use **'**

```
$start = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$start = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
```